# Cannot select and change contents via .prev on jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following jQuery:

```
// get position on new/removed items
function get_new_position_for_all_items() {
    $("li.sortable_shop_item input.sortable_shop_item_position").each(function(index) {
    $(this).val(index + 1);
  });
}

// remove shop_state_fields
function remove_fields(link) {
  $(link).prev("input.destroy_field").val("1");
    $(link).prev(".sortable_shop_item_position").attr('class', 'not_sortable');
  $(link).closest(".fields").hide("slow");
    get_new_position_for_all_items();
}
```

When I click the `remove_fields()` link, it will change the value of `input.destroy_field` which is initially `0`. Then it will hide the element with the closest `.fields` and calls the function `get_new_position_for_all_items()`.

The problem I am having is that I can't change the class of the nearest `.sortable_shop_item_position` to something else, so that when `get_new_position_for_all_items()` this field that has been removed will not be included in the sorting of new position.

I have tried doing something simple such as changing the value of `.sortable_shop_item_position`, but I just can't seem to have jQuery to identify and select it.

Note that there are several `.sortable_shop_item_position` which are wrapped in `li`.

Please advise. Many thanks.

[UPDATE 1]
Here's some rough HTML:

```
<li class="fields sortable_shop_item">
<p style="background-color: yellow; margin: 10px">
<span class="handle">[drag]</span>
<br>
<input id="country_shops_attributes_1_country_date" type="text" value="2012-02-02" size="30" name="country[shops_attributes][1][country_date]">
<label for="country_shops_attributes_1_country_date">country Date</label>
<br>
<input id="country_shops_attributes_1_position" class="sortable_shop_item_position" type="text" value="3" size="30" name="country[shops_attributes][1][position]">
<label for="country_shops_attributes_1_position">Position</label>
<br>
<input id="country_shops_attributes_1__destroy" class="destroy_field" type="hidden" value="false" name="country[shops_attributes][1][_destroy]">
<a onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;" href="#">remove</a>
</p>
<li class="fields sortable_shop_item">
<p style="background-color: yellow; margin: 10px">
<span class="handle">[drag]</span>
<br>
<input id="country_shops_attributes_2_country_date" type="text" value="2012-02-02" size="30" name="country[shops_attributes][2][country_date]">
<label for="country_shops_attributes_2_country_date">country Date</label>
<br>
<input id="country_shops_attributes_2_position" class="sortable_shop_item_position" type="text" value="3" size="30" name="country[shops_attributes][2][position]">
<label for="country_shops_attributes_2_position">Position</label>
<br>
<input id="country_shops_attributes_2__destroy" class="destroy_field" type="hidden" value="false" name="country[shops_attributes][2][_destroy]">
<a onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;" href="#">remove</a>
</p>
<li class="fields sortable_shop_item">
<p style="background-color: yellow; margin: 10px">
<span class="handle">[drag]</span>
<br>
<input id="country_shops_attributes_3_country_date" type="text" value="2012-02-02" size="30" name="country[shops_attributes][3][country_date]">
<label for="country_shops_attributes_3_country_date">country Date</label>
<br>
<input id="country_shops_attributes_3_position" class="sortable_shop_item_position" type="text" value="3" size="30" name="country[shops_attributes][3][position]">
<label for="country_shops_attributes_3_position">Position</label>
<br>
<input id="country_shops_attributes_3__destroy" class="destroy_field" type="hidden" value="false" name="country[shops_attributes][3][_destroy]">
<a onclick="remove_fields(this); return false;" href="#">remove</a>
</p>
```

You will notice each `<li>` is almost repeated, but with different in its sub-element. When I remove the `<li>` with `.sortable_shop_item_position` valued `2`, I want to replace this `.sortable_shop_item_position` with `.not_sortable` so that this class will be skipped when re-sorting.

Comment: Including the HTML for the page would be incredibly useful.

Comment: What is the result of the `$(link).prev(".sortable_shop_item_position")` expression? Does it contain any elements?

Comment: @AnthonyGrist: Updated with HTML.

Comment: @TimRogers: I can't be sure. It seems like it can't find the element with `.sortable_shop_item_position`. How can I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.prev` gets *the immediately preceding sibling of each element* http://api.jquery.com/prev/

Try `$.prevAll` for the second one, although you may have to use a more specific selector if you have multiple .sortable_shop_item_position elements. http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

Alternatively, if your DOM structure is:

```
sortable_shop_item_position
destroy_field
link
```

then you can use

```
$(link).prev().prev(".sortable_shop_item_position").attr('class', 'not_sortable');
```

Also, for improved performance, <del>pass link into that function as a jQuery DOM object</del> bind remove_links to the elements and use `$(this)` i.e. `$('a.classname').click(function() { /* contents of remove_links function */ });`, rather than just `this`. Each time you call `$(link)`, jQuery has to find that element in the DOM again. If you call the function using `remove_fields($('#linkidselector'))`, then you just need to use `link.prev()`. Or just `var el = $(link)`, then use `el.prev();`

Further, you could also chain that entire command:

```
$(link).prev("input.destroy_field").val("1").prev(".sortable_shop_item_position")
.attr('class', 'not_sortable').end()
.closest(".fields").hide("slow");
```

**UPDATE for newly provided HTML structure**: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HSv7m/

Using `prevAll` will be fine because the other element you want to modify is a *sibling* of the link element. The other `.sortable_shop_item_position` elements are under a different parent `LI` element, so `prevAll` won't access them when it shouldn't.

```
$(link).prev("input.destroy_field").val("1").prevAll(".sortable_shop_item_position")
.attr('class', 'not_sortable').end()
.closest(".fields").hide("slow");
```

Comment: Thanks @Benno, I updated my question with HTML. Please advise if there is any changes needed on your answer. I will try your answer later. Thanks again.

Comment: @Victor, sorry about the delayed reply. I've updated with my response. `prevAll` is your best option in this case.

Comment: nice! It works like charm. Just wondering, I actually tried testing with `.val("999")` instead of `.attr('class', 'not_sortable')`, but the former didn't work. There is existing value though. Do you know why? Thanks a million!

Comment: Hmmm. Not too sure why it wouldn't work for you? I noticed that while watching it in Firebug, and alerting the value before and after setting with `$.val`, that it was 3 before and 999 after, BUT the value didn't appear to change in Firebug. I then changed `$.val` to `$.attr('value','999')`, and ran it again, and it alerted 3 and 999, but this time, it DID display the change in Firebug. Did you try alerting it to see what the actual value was? `alert($(link).prev("input.destroy_field").prevAll(".sortable_shop_item_position").val())`

Comment: I shall try it. Am grateful for your help and advice. Many thanks.